# Centering text vertically in button

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, cross-platform

It should be simple to center text in a button. Unfortunately, across different browsers and platforms, I get different results.

I've tried for hours to fix it, but nothing works everywhere.

### Chrome, mac OS X:

[image]
<sub>(source: [d.pr](http://d.pr/i/c6Vt.jpg))</sub>

### Chrome, Windows 8

[image]
<sub>(source: [d.pr](http://d.pr/i/rwXX.jpg))</sub>

### IE 10, Windows 8

[image]
<sub>(source: [d.pr](http://d.pr/i/L7Jt.jpg))</sub>

So, yeah. The big block doesn't appear in IE if I set a defined height, but I don't get why it breaks down in the first place.

Here's the code:

```
.btn-call-to-action {
  background: #8e8287;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #f5f3e2;
  padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;

.btn-call-to-action a:after {
  content: url('../img/general-white-arrow.svg?1369574895');
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  right: 15px;
  top: 0px; }
```

and the HTML (pretty simple) :

```
<a href="about.html" class="btn-call-to-action">Want more ?</a>
```

and the site: http://aurelieremia.be/tfa/

// edit: I think I get it. Still not centered in windows but by resetting the line height, the button looks a bit more normal. IE problem resolved, I'll try using a background-image instead (thanks Ana)

Comment: what's the HTML going along with ?

Comment: can you tell what you want?

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui Response in the title : centering the text vertically. (across all browser/platforms)

Comment: Since the arrow is an image and not a Unicode character, you could set it as `background-image` for the button (and also free up a pseudo-element this way) with `background-position` set accordingly and tweaked `padding-right`.

Comment: @Ana Indeed, but I've set a transition on it (didn't put the code here) on hover.

Comment: check by embedding it on your page. like `<embed src="circle1.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />`

Comment: @Naemy: Do you mean the fact that it moves to the right? You *can* transition `background-position`.

Comment: i made it up just with one link :).

Comment: @Ana Right. Out of curiosity, is there any advantage of using background-image instead of after ? (apart from having less markup)

Comment: Freeing up one pseudo-element and creating a simple solution for the centering problem. Isn't that enough? Test http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/f0e39bb00feae10da72b59c987ccc661

Comment: @Ana Oh! I didn't realized it was what caused Internet Explorer to break down. Thanks !

Comment: @Ana On problem I have though is I can't place the background from the right, therefore I have to set pixels => not very reusable code. I think I'll keep the pseudo element and set its position to absolute.

Comment: You could use the 4 value `background-position` (something like `background-position: right 10px top 50%`). The problem with this  is that, as far as I know (haven't tested recently), it doesn't work in current Safari because of a bug. I'm also thinking that using `calc()` for `background-position` might work (something like `background-position: calc(100%-10px) 50%` - never actually tried this though...), but, sadly, Opera doesn't support it.

Comment: Test for this http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/LBHqx

Comment: @Ana Pretty cool, didn't know about this functionality. I think I'll stick with the pseudos elements for now, and switch when the browser compatibility issues are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help but cross browser centering in css is a big pain so I use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) and overwrite some of the classes.

If this sounds like something you'd consider you can check out the solution [here](http://html5devgal.com/blog/2013/05/29/vertically-and-horizontally-center-with-twitter-bootstrap-responsive/)

Comment: Cool to know I'm not the only one. I'll check it out, thank you ! Note: my problem there is more cross-platform than cross browser though :)

Answer (score 0):

Leave :after in static .
vertical-align to middle or explicite value (depends of where really stand arrow in svg/img).
white-space:nowrap to parent box to secure, but not necessary:
http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/vzrGj

Comment: i have no Ie10 and i expect it to behave normal, at least with basic CSS.

Comment: that's what he did(used basic CSS) btw take care next time.

Comment: ... without giving html structure - off i go.

Comment: @GCyrillus It's pretty much the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

HTML:

```
    <a href="about.html">
        <div class="btn-call-to-action">
            <span>Want more?  <img src="http://bkids.sisuweb.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/postArrowR.png" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </a>
```

CSS:

```
    .btn-call-to-action{
        width:160px;
        height:80px;
        background: #8e8287;
        padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px;
        margin:8px;
        color: #f5f3e2;
        border-radius: 2px;
        display:table;
        text-align:center;
    }

    .btn-call-to-action span{
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MQHVE/3/

The important part here is to have the wrapper (the a tag) display:table and the content (span) display:table-cell. Then you can apply vertical-align:middle to the span.

Comment: Thank you for your input ! Table is useful to center elements, but I'd prefer to avoid it when not essential, especially for a simple button.

Comment: Fair enough, though you might find that it is the simplest and most straightforward way to center your text vertically. Bear in mind that the concern over using tables for tabular data only generally concerns only HTML tables, not necessarily css table styling.